# How to override attributes of a style in a android view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how to override style attributes of a referenced style. Doing it by simply placing the attributes does not seem to be a solution - See `insetLeft`. That property is part of material button view itself, but setting the property has no impact on the style.

my layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clickable="true"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:insetLeft="0dp"
    android:insetRight="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serverIp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serverLastContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot use/override attributes for LinearLayout or any other builtin views. You can only do so in your own custom view, where you have to retrieve the attribute values and use them to change your view behavior/appearance. Here is the official doc https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like `insetLeft` is part of the style you reference `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton`. Let's ascend the hierarchy by entering Ctrl-B on each style reference.

This is the style definition i material-1.4.0 values.xml:

```
</style>
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_padding_right</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">@dimen/mtrl_btn_text_btn_icon_padding</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_text_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_btn_ripple_color</item>
  </style>
```

Now, let's look at "Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton":

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@animator/mtrl_btn_unelevated_state_list_anim</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

The hierarchy ends there. I don't see the `insetLeft` attribute referenced anywhere, so you can't be overriding it in your layout - a least through the `style` reference in your layout.

Specify what you are trying to do for an answer that might help.

Comment: Can you add some reference to where you get those sources without IDE support?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can follow below steps:

1. Go to styles.xml and make a new style with parent as "Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton". Example:

```
<style name="CustomButtonLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

2. Use the created style in your xml viewgroup. Example:

```
style="@style/CustomButtonLayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the attribute explicitly overrides it's declaration from the style.

However, you're applying a View style to a Layout, not all attributes will have an impact on the drawing of that view.